# Android Espresso 2 cannot click custom dialog button on Nexus 9

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a custom dialog with a button. When I open the dialog, my Espresso2 test wants to click the button.

```
onView(...).perform(click());
```

The test works with Nexus5 emulator, but fails in Nexus9 emulator.

Surprisingly it works with the AlertDialog from the support library. I tracked it down, what the library does different to my implementation. 
Basically I got it to work just by setting a Window flags:

```
mWindow.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

I have no idea why this flag is required and what it does.

Should I use this flag?

Comment: try to use code like `onView(withText(R.s‌​tring.test_account)).‌​inRoot(isDialog()).ch‌​eck(matches(isDisplay‌​ed()))`;

Answer (score 0):

If you use the UI-Automator with AndroidX, you can find the dialog and buttons.

It is a gradle dependency code.

```
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
}
```

You can reach the button with this code.

It is Kotlin code.

```
val button = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
                .findObject(
                    UiSelector().text(
                        activityTestRule
                            .activity
                            .getString(R.string.button)
                            .toUpperCase()
                    )
                )

if (button.exists() && button.isEnabled) {
    button.click()
}
```